# “No input file specified” - Laravel project on CentOS

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php7, laravel

I've have VM with CentOS installed where I want to host Laravel project. I've put it on `/var/www/html/project`

But when I access via URL of this project like `127.0.0.1/project` I get tree of document. When I enter `public` directory it shows me a message: "`No input file specified.`".

What I need to do to solve this problem? I've edited httpd.conf file(added V-host). Welcome page of Apache works good.

This is version of PHP:

```
PHP 7.4.19 (cli) (built: May  4 2021 11:06:37) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Apache:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (centos)
Server built:   Jun 29 2021 20:08:24
```

Below I list all of services which I got installed on server:

```
UNIT                                                  LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
atd.service                                           loaded active running Job spooling tools
auditd.service                                        loaded active running Security Auditing Service
chronyd.service                                       loaded active running NTP client/server
crond.service                                         loaded active running Command Scheduler
dbus.service                                          loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus
dracut-shutdown.service                               loaded active exited  Restore /run/initramfs on shutdown
firewalld.service                                     loaded active running firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
getty@tty1.service                                    loaded active running Getty on tty1
httpd.service                                         loaded active running The Apache HTTP Server
import-state.service                                  loaded active exited  Import network configuration from initramfs
irqbalance.service                                    loaded active running irqbalance daemon
kdump.service                                         loaded active exited  Crash recovery kernel arming
kmod-static-nodes.service                             loaded active exited  Create list of required static device nodes for the cu>
libstoragemgmt.service                                loaded active running libstoragemgmt plug-in server daemon
lvm2-monitor.service                                  loaded active exited  Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeve>
lvm2-pvscan@8:3.service                               loaded active exited  LVM event activation on device 8:3
mcelog.service                                        loaded active running Machine Check Exception Logging Daemon
mysqld.service                                        loaded active running MySQL 8.0 database server
NetworkManager-wait-online.service                    loaded active exited  Network Manager Wait Online
NetworkManager.service                                loaded active running Network Manager
nis-domainname.service                                loaded active exited  Read and set NIS domainname from /etc/sysconfig/network
php-fpm.service                                       loaded active running The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
plymouth-quit-wait.service                            loaded active exited  Hold until boot process finishes up
plymouth-quit.service                                 loaded active exited  Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen
plymouth-read-write.service                           loaded active exited  Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data
plymouth-start.service                                loaded active exited  Show Plymouth Boot Screen
polkit.service                                        loaded active running Authorization Manager
rhsmcertd.service                                     loaded active running Enable periodic update of entitlement certificates.
rngd-wake-threshold.service                           loaded active exited  Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Wake threshold service
rngd.service                                          loaded active running Hardware RNG Entropy Gatherer Daemon
rsyslog.service                                       loaded active running System Logging Service
smartd.service                                        loaded active running Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon
sshd.service                                          loaded active running OpenSSH server daemon
sssd.service                                          loaded active running System Security Services Daemon
systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-AEDD\x2dEA4B.service loaded active exited  File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/AEDD-EA4B
systemd-journal-flush.service                         loaded active exited  Flush Journal to Persistent Storage
systemd-journald.service                              loaded active running Journal Service
systemd-logind.service                                loaded active running Login Service
systemd-modules-load.service                          loaded active exited  Load Kernel Modules
systemd-random-seed.service                           loaded active exited  Load/Save Random Seed
systemd-remount-fs.service                            loaded active exited  Remount Root and Kernel File Systems
systemd-sysctl.service                                loaded active exited  Apply Kernel Variables
systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                    loaded active exited  Create Static Device Nodes in /dev
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                        loaded active exited  Create Volatile Files and Directories
systemd-udev-trigger.service                          loaded active exited  udev Coldplug all Devices
systemd-udevd.service                                 loaded active running udev Kernel Device Manager
systemd-update-utmp.service                           loaded active exited  Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown
systemd-user-sessions.service                         loaded active exited  Permit User Sessions
tuned.service                                         loaded active running Dynamic System Tuning Daemon
user-runtime-dir@1000.service                         loaded active exited  /run/user/1000 mount wrapper
user@1000.service                                     loaded active running User Manager for UID 1000
vdo.service                                           loaded active exited  VDO volume services
vgauthd.service                                       loaded active running VGAuth Service for open-vm-tools
vmtoolsd.service                                      loaded active running Service for virtual machines hosted on VMware
```

Is any solution to that?

I've appended configuration at end of `httpd.conf` located at: `/etc/httpd/conf`:

```
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# See the httpd.conf(5) man page for more information on this configuration,
# and httpd.service(8) on using and configuring the httpd service.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so 'log/access_log'
# with ServerRoot set to '/www' will be interpreted by the
# server as '/www/log/access_log', where as '/log/access_log' will be
# interpreted as '/log/access_log'.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
# Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
# same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
# least PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User apache
Group apache

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin root@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts.
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

#
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# Specify a default charset for all content served; this enables
# interpretation of all content as UTF-8 by default.  To use the
# default browser choice (ISO-8859-1), or to allow the META tags
# in HTML content to override this choice, comment out this
# directive:
#
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it,
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults if commented: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile on

# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/project/public"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You only show that the command line version of PHP is installed. Is the apache module installed and enabled?

Comment: Yes, you got httpd service listed above. As I mentioned it's showing welcome page of apache.

Comment: The welcome page is static HTML. No PHP is needed for it. Nothing of your output shows if the PHP module is enabled in Apache.

Comment: You have a PHP-FPM service running, but your apache is not configured to use it.

Comment: Okay, so I've enabled php-fpm. Could you instruct me, where I can configure it?

Comment: @wpcpremium80 Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User. Where is the Relevance, as you seems not to be a Business Administrator, else you would know how, please move your question to superuser

Comment: I've posted on stack, they told me that I should post on server fault.. then where actually should I write?